# PHP use SESSION in the multiple pages

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, session-variables, session-cookies

I have 1 SESSION variable that will load when a login form is inserted and it passes the test. But, the variable will only work in one page and when I click on a different page that includes the same file which gives me the SESSION, it doesn't work. It will only work for pages that are linked to the form. I am using the post method. **sample.php** <- site that is in action="sample.php" therefore its linked.

Beginning code for **sample.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
require 'php/login_admin.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['admin']))
    echo ' all html code ';
```

Code for **login_admin.php**

```
if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password'])
        {
            session_set_cookie_params(3000, "/");
            $_SESSION['admin'] = 'open';

        } else {
            session_close();
            echo "Wrong password and username!";
        }
```

**NOTE** I have this same set up for all pages and I do not know why only the pages linked directly to the form in the **action** attribute work.

Comment: `session_start();` needed on each-page on top where you want to use session. so add that on each of your page where you are trying to access session data.Also remove `session_close();` from there. No need

Comment: If you have this on every page - the other pages will cause a failure of your users username and password test as you are running this on every page and close the session - session_close() will be run every time you have not submitted the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all your OTHER pages you only need to test for the admin session and if that fails then redirect to the login page... or display it... whatever you decide. But let's assume we go to a dedicated admin login page for fun...

So on All your other pages...except the login page...

```
<?php
session_start(); 
// Is the admin logged in? 
if (!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
{
   header("location:admin_login.php");
   exit();
}

echo ' all html code ';
```